# Write exponents in MATLAB GUI pop-up menu

Tags: matlab, user-interface, popup, exponent

Is there any way I can write exponents other than `²` and `³` as part of a string in a MATLAB GUI popup menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just type [number]^[power], it will automatically cast as power notation

Answer (score 1):

Matlab `uicontrols` [support HTML](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/html-support-in-matlab-uicomponents/).

Thus, you can create a popup menu with arbitrary exponents like so (just set the `string` property if you have created it via GUIDE):

```
fh = figure;
uicontrol('style','popupmenu','parent',fh,'units','normalized','position',[0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4],...
   'string','<html>text<sup>exp</sup></html>')
```